# Textarea is briefly visible before TinyMCE renders

Tags: tinymce

I am using the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor for a ASP.NET MVC project.  Although the editor is working, when the page loads the underlying textarea is visible for a brief moment before the editor kicks in - the raw textarea is visible for about, give or take, a second.  Is there a way to only load the content once the TinyMCE editor is ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Bootstrap and if I assign the textarea a class of `hide` (which essentially is just a `display: none` CSS style) the textarea is hidden, and the editor renders when it's initialized.

Comment: Thanks. With Modernizr:  .js textarea { display: none; }

Answer (score 0):

Populate the data on the TinyMCE's init event.

```
function myCustomOnInit() { 
        alert("We are ready to rumble!!");
}

tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        oninit : myCustomOnInit
});
```

code from http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:oninit

Comment: This wouldn't work because the data is passed to the view from the controller in the viewmodel.  It would be a bit of a hack to populate the data on the `init` event.  What I could do is hide the textarea and re-display it on init event, but I realised that just hiding the textarea (see my answer below) does the trick on it's own.